# Assigning NSMutableString from NSString Warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I have the following three lines of code in my program:

```
NSMutableString *stringOne = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Hello "];
NSMutableString *stringTwo = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"World"];
NSMutableString *sayIt = [stringOne stringByAppendingString:stringTwo];
```

Despite the fact that it works, the third line is causing the warning Assigning NSMutableString * from NSString *.

I am at a loss here since everything I am using is an NSMutableString.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not quite. `stringByAppendingString` does not return an `NSMutableString`. Instead do the following:

```
NSMutableString *sayIt = [NSMutableString stringWithString:stringOne];
[sayIt appendString:stringTwo];
```

Or

```
NSMutableString *sayIt = [[stringOne stringByAppendingString:stringTwo] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Alternatively: `NSMutableString *sayIt = [[stringOne stringByAppendingString:stringTwo] mutableCopy];`

Comment: I actually figured out XJones solution right after I posted the question.  Aaron Brager's work's like a champ as well.  I assumed that since I was calling stringByAppendingString from an NSMutableString that it would return an NSMutableString as well.  That's what I get for assuming.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I answered my own question at the same time both of you posted as well :)  Better three answers than none!

Comment: there are other ways to do it. the key is simply realizing that `NSString` methods called on `NSMutableString` instances still return `NSString`. Not sure how you're using this in the context of your app but I would only use mutable strings when necessary. In your original example, `stringOne` and `stringTwo` can be `NSString` and only `sayIt` needs to be mutable. That's also assuming you change the string in other ways later. Anyhow, happy to help.

Comment: Thanks.  I do need a single NSMutableString for what I am doing.  I just wrote the simple example above to show the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I just realized that `stringByAppendingString:` returns an `NSString` despite calling it from an `NSMutableString` object.  Since I am dealing with `NSMutableString`, I should have used that class's `appendString:` method.  The new code that works without a warning is:

```
NSMutableString *stringOne = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Hello "];
NSMutableString *stringTwo = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"World"];
[stringOne appendString:stringTwo];
```